# Does anyone recognise this jet engine?

Tags: feature-identification

[image]

sorry for the terrible quality, it's what I've got. I've not been able to find anything looking like it using google image search. It looks too detailed for a random bit of clip art.

Possibly around 12-15 feet long by 2-3 feet diameter

Comment: where have you found that image? in what context?

Comment: it's an image that was pasted into a line drawing of an experimental apparatus. Bits of it may have been modified @Federico I'd be interested to know where the image originally came from too.

Comment: looks more like a generic "this is a jet engine" picture than anything indicating a specific model.

Comment: that could well be @jwenting, it just looked like a few too many McGuffins - although they're quite tame by real engine standards.

Comment: You'll need looking at Jane's, they publish yearly about aircraft engines, or in the work by Ricard Miguel Vidal: 'El motor de aviación de la A la Z', free and open access for AEHS members. Salut +

Comment: I accepted my answer as I believe it is correct, and don't want to pollute the unaccepted answers pool, but I will happily accept anyone else's better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a fairly good match for the Rolls Royce F405 Ardour. I can't quite work out which version though....

Thanks to everyone who spent time looking.

[image: Rolls Royce F405 Ardour]
<sub><sup>[Rolls-royce.com](https://www.rolls-royce.com/products-and-services/defence/aerospace.aspx)</sup></sub>

here's an afterburner and nozzle for a variant:

[image]
<sub><sup>[Hunini](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Hunini)</sup></sub>